# Need to make the row in normal mode after updating

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with "Edit Update Cancel" command field. When I click Edit, all the columns in the particular row becomes editable and when I click update, the Table is updated based on the new values.
Then the Gridview is binded with the updated datatable. But the "Update Cancel" button still 
remains.

[image]

Once the row , has been updated, the "Update Cancel" button has to be changed to "Edit"  So how is that made possible.

Thanks in Advance

This is the code for updating and displaying the updated data

```
 protected void StaticNoticeGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {                
                //Gets the updated value from GridView
                string id = StaticNoticeGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
                string updatedItem = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
                string updatedURL = e.NewValues[1].ToString();

                //Updated the Database
                StaticNoticeController staticNoticeController = new StaticNoticeController();
                int rocordsAffected = staticNoticeController.UpdateStaticNoticeData(updatedItem, updatedURL, id);

                //Gets the updated datatable and binds the Gridview again
                if (rocordsAffected == 1)
                {
                    this.StaticNoticeGridView.DataSource = null;
                    this.StaticNoticeGridView.DataSource = staticNoticeController.GetStaticNoticeData();
                    this.StaticNoticeGridView.DataBind();
                }
            }
            catch(SystemException ex)
            {
                //ToDo: Log the Exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show the code you use for the update click event handler.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks.. Code has been added to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set GridView1.EditIndex = -1;before `this.StaticNoticeGridView.DataBind();`in the method `StaticNoticeGridView_RowUpdating`

Comment: That answered my question too, I was having a slightly different problem which was my GridView was showing editable rows on PostBack even when that wasn't my goal. I really don't know why I have never encountered this problem before, but hey at least now I have my answer. This was driving me mad, Thanks!